# Plotting panel data with Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I have three columns: **id**, **year**, **data**. How can I simply plot in Excel the time series of the values in **data** (i.e. **data** on the Y-axis and **year** on the X-axis), for each **id**? So for instance, if I have three different identifiers (i.e. three values for **id**), I will have three different time series on the same plot (one for each **id**).

It must be super easy but I'm not a big user of Excel,

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

First plot a single series. In this case, I'm sorting by ID then Year and plotting only ID value of A:

[image]

Then right-click on chart and choose "Select Data". Then ADD series B. Then repeat for series C.

Results:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Pivotcharts are what you are looking for - especially if you have more than three series :)

Select all your data, click insert ribbon > Pivot Chart.

Follow the prompts. Once you get to the PivotTable Fields, drag ID to "Legends (Series)" or Columns, year to "Axis (Categories)" or Rows and DATA to Values.

Now look for "Row Labels" in the pivot table (the first column with dates), click the little drop down arrow and select "sort smallest to largest".

Comment: Thanks a lot ! But doing that, all my DATA values become "1" in the pivot table . How come?

Comment: In a pivot table, computations are made (in the Values field). Is it possible to have exactly the same thing, without computations?

Comment: Summarize by Sum rather than by Count.

Comment: Yes indeed, since you only have one data point (year, data) per ID, the sum of one value is the value itself :) The default when you drag data to Values should actually be sum, unless there is maybe text data which causes excel to jump to count.